# How to send event to Sentry without Sentry-SDK?

Tags: python, logging, alert, monitoring, sentry

I need to run Python script without external dependencies so I can not use SDK for python. I also do not want call external tools like sentry-cli from script for that purpouse

I need simply send two events to specific Project, using DSN.

I can not google it or find in [API reference](https://docs.sentry.io/api/)(there only methods about listing\retrivieng issues/events but not sending them)

So my question is how to send event to sentry project using DSN?

Answer (score 2):

The same way any of the SDKs does: post the data to Sentry API for the given DSN. There are multiple sources you can use to build that:

- read up on Sentry SDK development docs: https://develop.sentry.dev/sdk/envelopes/
- have a look into Sentry python SDK source code to see what's going on and reimplement the pieces you need (keep the code license in mind): https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python
- Try the Sentry JavaSCript SDK and post an even through browser devtools console, then you can see the exact payload on the network tab.